# В чем разница обновления по F5 в Firefox'e и др. браузерах (IE и Chrom'e)

Tags: firefox, кэширование

После обновление страницы с помощью нажатия <kbd>F5</kbd> в `firefox` выглядет иначе, нежели в *IE* или *Chrom*'e. Даже если перед обновлением страницы в *firefox* почистить кеш браузера.

В чем причина, и как форсировать поведения страницы как при <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>?

Comment: Понятность текста: 25%

Comment: вот, уже исправил

Comment: Некоторые страницы в разных браузерах выглят уж совсем по разному и F5 тут не поможет (поможет только отказ от браузер).

А так - похоже, что разные браузеры по разному кешируют данные. Открывайте по F12 консоль, переходите на вкладку Network и сравнивайте, что отдалось закешированным, а что нет.

Comment: в том то и дело, что кеш полностью отключил через about:config: все установил в false:
network.http.use-cache
browser.cache.offline.enable
browser.cache.disk.enable
browser.cache.disk_cache_ssl
browser.cache.memory.enable

Comment: Кажется понял, дело в истории

Comment: Технически проблему решил в апликации (действительно все высвечивающиеся "неправильные" данные были взяты из истории), но реально так и не понял почему в фаерфоксе эта проблема возникала, а в других браузерах нет. Поэтому, думаю, мне не следует отвечать на свой вопрос, так как разобрался только внутри апликации (решение с проверкой юзерагента), а ситуация с браузером так и осталась неясной для меня.

Comment: Хочу уточнить (из вопроса так и не понял): проблема была в том, что остается в HTML-формах (<input> и пр.) после перезагрузки? Или про какую историю речь?